# c++ how to print how many times each integer appears in the STL list

Tags: c++, list, count, stl, operators

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> numbers; list<int> numb;

    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        numbers.push_back(rand() % 20);

    list<int>::iterator it;

    for (it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to use `std::count()` but I am not able to do it right. I tried  to do the following:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> numbers; list<int> numb;

    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        numbers.push_back(rand() % 20);

    list<int>::iterator it;

    for (it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";

        while (it != numbers.begin() && it != numbers.end())
        {
            ++it;
            *it = count(it, numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
            cout << " " << *it;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But it gives me an error:

> binary == no operator found which takes a left hand operator type 'int' (or there is not acceptable conversion).

I know I am doing something wrong.

I also tried a few more things, like `int numb = std::count(numbers.begin()), numbers.end(), *it)`, but it didn't work either.  So, I want to know if there is a special operator to count values in a list.

Comment: 1) Did you read the documentation of [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)? Hint: there's example section. 2) "_ I also tried a few more things <...> but it didn't work either_" Please explain **how** didn't it work. Such statement, on its own, provides nothing useful to the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, using a map is a better approach to your problem, but if you have to solve it using lists here is one possible solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> numbers, unique_num, numb;
    int num;

    // Create both the original list and a list that
    // will be left with only unique numbers
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        num = rand() % 20;
        numbers.push_back(num);
        unique_num.push_back(num);
    }

    // Sort and select the unique numbers
    unique_num.sort();
    unique_num.unique();

    // Count unique numbers and store the count in numb
    std::list<int>::iterator iter = unique_num.begin();
    while (iter != unique_num.end())
        numb.push_back(count(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), *iter++));

    // Print the results
    for(std::list<int>::iterator iter1 = unique_num.begin(), iter2 = numb.begin();
            iter2 != numb.end(); iter1++, iter2++)
        std::cout<< "Number " << *iter1 << " appears " <<
          *iter2 << ( *iter2 > 1 ? " times " : " time" ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program uses another list, `unique_num`, to hold unique numbers occurring in `numbers`. That list is initially created identical to `numbers` and is then sorted and the duplicates are removed.

The program then iterates through numbers in that unique list and uses count to get the number of occurrences of each of them in the original `numbers` list. The number of occurrences is then stored in a new list, `numb`.

When printing, the program uses a ternary operator to check whether it should print "time" or "times" depending whether the result implies one or more than one occurrence.

Note - if you want different list values each time you run your program you need to change the random seed using `srand`. Include the header `#include <time.h>` in your program and the line `srand(time(NULL));` at the beginning of your main.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. One question, what is the difference between numbers.push_back(rand() % 20 and num = rand() % 20; numbers.push_back(num)???

Comment: Glad to help :) Still, did you cover maps already? Is this for a class? Because really the map solution is what you may want to do in the future. In the current version, since the program is adding the same random number to both lists, it first generates the number (`num`) and then adds it to the lists. Otherwise it would assign different numbers. I'm about to add one thing related to rand that is important.

Comment: Yes this is for my c++ class, We haven’t covered maps yet but we will next week. I really appreciate your suggestions, they really helped me understand the project better. I’ll check your information about Rand.

Comment: If you have any more questions about this code, ask in the comment and I'll clarify in the answer. After reading, just give it a shot with and without srand, you'll see :)

Comment: Just a note that, handy as it is, `using namespace std;` is considered a bit of bad practice since it literally litters the namespace with hundreds of unneeded symbols.  Use `using std::list; using std::cout;` (etc), and if too many of these are needed they can go in a separate header file.

Comment: I am only suggesting to perhaps replace the code.  A separate note, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49302034/4653379) in your other post, would incite yet more commentary, what may be excessive here since this is constrained being a class project.

Comment: @zdim thank you, I will. I don't know why I haven't here - nowadays (2 months later ;) I wouldn't miss that. I didn't know about the symbols, I just thought of accidental overwriting. So you think I should just change the code without any comments?

Comment: That's what I'd think, yes.  If there is a comment on that there are other things to comment on, while it's a class project.  I'd just either replace `using namespace std;` with `using std::list;` (etc) or even simply remove it and have `std::list` (etc) in the code.

Comment: @zdim Edited. I went with the later and applied it to `cout` and `endl` too. I thought that without additional comments using `std::` everywhere is more logical and leaves it to the future user to check the background behind it and the alternatives. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the signature for `std::count` again. It takes three parameters `std::count(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val);` and it returns the number of occurrences of `val` in your data set. So something like this should work for you where `theNumber` is the number you're counting.

```
#include <algorithm>

int occurrences = std::count(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), theNumber);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using iterators correctly (you are modifying `it` while you are still using it to iterate the list), and you are not calling `std::count()` correctly.

The code should look more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> numbers;
    int numb;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        numbers.push_back(std::rand() % 20);

    std::list<int>::iterator it;    

    for (it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); ++it)
    {
        numb = std::count(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), *it);
        std::cout << *it << " " << numb << std::endl;
    }

    /* or:
    for (int value : numbers)
    {
        numb = std::count(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), value);
        std::cout << value << " " << numb << std::endl;
    }
    */

    return 0;
}
```

But, like others said, you should use a `std::map` to track the counts, so you can account for duplicates, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> numbers;
    std::map<int, int> numb;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        numbers.push_back(rand() % 20);

    for (std::list<int>::iterator it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); ++it)
        numb[*it]++;

    /* or:
    for (int value : numbers)
        numb[value]++;
    */

    for (std::map<int, int>::iterator it = numb.begin(); it != numb.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;

    /* or:
    for (auto &item : numb)
        std::cout << item.first << " " << item.second << std::endl;
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Which can be reduced to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> numb;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        numb[rand() % 20]++;

    for (std::map<int, int>::iterator it = numb.begin(); it != numb.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;

    /* or:
    for (auto &item : numb)
        std::cout << item.first << " " << item.second << std::endl;
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a map:

```
map<int, int> counts;
for(int val : Numbers)
  ++counts[val];
```

Answer (score 0):

**WITH ADDITIONAL MEMORY:**

You can use buckets, to get complexity O(N + MAX_NUM). So when MAX_NUM <= N we have O(N):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

const int MAX_NUM = 20;
const int N = 10;

int main() {
    std::list<int> numbers;
    int buckets[MAX_NUM];

    std::fill(buckets, buckets + MAX_NUM, 0);

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) numbers.push_back(rand() % MAX_NUM);

    // computing
    for (auto it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); ++it) {
        buckets[*it]++;
    }

    //printing answers
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM; i++) {
        if (buckets[i]) std::cout << "value " << i << " appears in the list " << buckets[i] << " times." <<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For big data i would recommend using std::unordered_map for buckets and then geting complexity O(N) (thanks to hashing):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <unordered_map>

const int N = 10;
const int MAX_NUM = 20;
int main() {
    std::list<int> numbers;
    std::unordered_map<int, int> buckets;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) numbers.push_back(rand() % MAX_NUM);

    // computing
    for (auto it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); ++it) {
        buckets[*it]++;
    }

    //printing answers
    for (auto & k_v : buckets) {
        std::cout << "value " << k_v.first << " appears in the list " << k_v.second << " times." <<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**WITHOUT ADDITIONAL MEMORY:**

In more universal way, you can use std::vector instead of std::list and std::sort on it, and then count value changes in a simple for. Complexity is O(N log N):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

const int N = 10;
const int MAX_NUM = 20;

int main() {
    std::vector<int> numbers;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) numbers.push_back(rand() % MAX_NUM);

    // sorting
    std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

    //printing answers for sorted vector
    if (numbers.size() > 0) {
        int act_count = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            if (numbers[i] != numbers[i -1]) {
                std::cout << "value " << numbers[i-1] << " appears in the list " << act_count << " times." <<std::endl;
                act_count = 1;
            } else {
                act_count++;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "value " << numbers[numbers.size() - 1] << " appears in the list " << act_count << " times." <<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can also do the above on std::list, getting also O(nlogn), but can't use std::sort:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <ctime>

const int N = 10;
const int MAX_NUM = 20;

int main() {
    std::list<int> numbers;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) numbers.push_back(rand() % MAX_NUM);

    // sorting
    numbers.sort();

    //printing answers for sorted list
    if (!numbers.empty()) {
        int act_count = 0;
        auto prev = numbers.begin();
        for (auto it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); it++) {
            if (*it != *prev) {
                std::cout << "value " << *it << " appears in the list " << act_count << " times." <<std::endl;
                act_count = 1;
            } else {
                act_count++;
            }
            prev = it;
        }
        std::cout << "value " << *prev << " appears in the list " << act_count << " times." <<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```